# prompt user for input to create multiplication table

Tags: javascript, html, css

The program almost works is there any way to make sure that when the user puts in the value it includes that value in the multiplication table

```
<html>
<head>
<title> multiplication </title>
<style> 
body{
font-family: arial;
font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<h3> Mulitplication table </h3>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter number </button>
<script language ="JavaScript">
function myFunction(){
var num = prompt("Please enter your number", 0);
document.write("<center><table border ='1px'>");
for var (a =1; a < num; a++) {
document.write("<tr style='height:40px'>");
for(var b =1; b<= 10; b++) {
document.write("<td style='width:40px'><center><font size = '4'>"  + a*b + "<.center></font></td>");
}
document.write("</tr>");
}
}
document.write("</table></center>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: you have a typo `document.wirite` and document.write is NOT like building a string. When you write out an element, it will be closed.

Comment: Also whatever course you are learning from is using really outdated html. font and center are deprecated tags and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of issues in your code, please check the below working example!

- Below line html tags were not closed properly, it should be `document.write`

  ```
  document.wirite("<center><table border ='1px');
  ```
- Since you are using multiplication tables, we need to have a row `tr` for each value so we can change the for loop to as shown below, the center tags were not closed properly too!

  ```
  for (var a = 1; a < num; a++) {
      document.write("<tr><td style='width:40px'><center><font size = '4'>" + a * num + "</center></font></td></tr>");
    }
  ```

Please refer the below example and let me know if you face any issues!

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> multiplication </title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <h3> Mulitplication table </h3>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Enter number </button>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function myFunction() {
      var num = prompt("Please enter your number", 0);
      document.write("<center><table border ='1px'>");
      for (var a = 1; a < num; a++) {
        document.write("<tr><td style='width:40px'><center><font size = '4'>" + a * num + "</center></font></td></tr>");
      }
      document.write("</table></center>");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```